# get_success_url with arguments after creation

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have 2 sections, one for normal users and one for admins (not related to Django admin). I have, for example, a Product Model.

In the Model I use get_absolute_url to set the detail url for normal users.

The Product creation is in the Admin section and the success_url, needs to go the newly created Product DetailView.

I need to get the new pk and use it the get_success_url.

```
  def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:detail_company', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

will give me the following error:

```
'AccountCompanyCreateView' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary key is an attribute of `self.object`, not `self` (the view itself).

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('accounts:detail_company', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: Been looking for this. How were you able to find out that it's an object of `self.object`?

Comment: @enchance it's mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object) for `CreateView`.